# Narrow eglot's area-of-effect in Vue.js file using web-mode?

Tags: web-mode, eglot

I'd like to use `eglot` and `web-mode` to edit some Vue.js single file components. These files have top level `<template>` and `<script>` sections, with the former containing HTML.

The Eglot syntaxt checking and completion is *very* confused by this. Is there a way to tell web-mode that I only want to have eglot enabled when I'm inside the `<script>` part of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by taking a different approach: using [vls](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/tree/master/server) and making a new major mode, derived from `web-mode`, to manage the association between Vue files and Eglot.

Wrote it up as [a blog post](https://genehack.blog/2020/08/web-mode-eglot-vetur-vuejs-=-happy/) with the details, but TL;DR:

```
(require 'eglot)
(require 'web-mode)
(define-derived-mode genehack-vue-mode web-mode "ghVue"
  "A major mode derived from web-mode, for editing .vue files with LSP support.")
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.vue\\'" . genehack-vue-mode))
(add-hook 'genehack-vue-mode-hook #'eglot-ensure)
(add-to-list 'eglot-server-programs '(genehack-vue-mode "vls"))
```

And then install `vls` with `npm install -g vls`.